# Installing Haskell dependencies like `pip -r requirements.pip`

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am new to Haskell and am having problems with `cabal`.

Performing the following operations,

```
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install parsec alex happy haddock mtl
```

Followed by

```
$ cabal configure --enable-tests
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Scheme-0.1.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
alex >=2.3, cabal >=1.22, haddock >=2.15, happy >=1.18
```

I am using

```
$ cabal --version                        
cabal-install version 1.22.8.0
using version 1.22.7.0 of the Cabal library
```

I deleted the sandbox and created a new one

```
$ cabal sandbox remove
$ cabal sandbox init
```

so that I could use:

```
$ cabal install --dependencies-only
$ cabal configure --enable-tests
```

But I suffer the same issue there, which is that both yield the same error, namely

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Scheme-0.1.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
alex >=2.3,
cabal >=1.22,
doctest >=0.8,
haddock >=2.15,
happy >=1.18
```

This is my `.cabal` file,

```
name:                       Scheme
version:                    0.1.0.0
license:                    MIT
license-file:               LICENSE
category:                   Language
build-type:                 Simple
cabal-version:              >=1.10

executable Scheme
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -Wall
  hs-source-dirs:      src/
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >=4.6 && <4.9
                       , cabal >=1.22
                       , parsec >=3.1 && <3.2
                       , alex >=2.3
                       , happy >=1.18
                       , haddock >=2.15
                       , mtl >=2.2.1

test-suite doctests
  default-language:   Haskell2010
  type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  ghc-options:        -threaded
  main-is:            doctests.hs
  build-depends:      base >=4.6 && <4.9
                       , alex >=2.3
                       , happy >=1.18
                       , haddock >=2.13
                       , doctest >= 0.8
```

I experience the same problems even without a sandbox.

In Python with `pip` this is just a matter of using a `virtualenv` and executing `pip install -r requirements.pip` if one has such a file specifying the dependencies. I'd like to go through a similar process, but with `cabal`.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: In general `cabal configure` should be done before `cabal install`.

Comment: "I experience the same problems even without a sandbox." I would expect this sequence of steps to be correct.. where exactly is `cabal install` placing those executables? Is this related to `--enable-tests` at all? Try `cabal sandbox init; cabal install --dependencies; cabal install -v3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
alex >=2.3, cabal >=1.22, haddock >=2.15, happy >=1.18
```

The missing deps here are *not* libraries but programs. You have run `cabal install` on them, but that installs them into a special cabal bin folder, typically under unix in `~/.cabal/bin` for user installs. (And in different locations for mac and windows).

So you need to ensure that that `bin` directory is in your path, *or* you need to move those executables to `/usr/bin` or the like that is already in your path.